# Second ssh instance won't start after upgrade to Xenial Xerus - Permission denied

Tags: 16.04, permissions, openssh, sshd

I've configured a second instance of my ssh-server. 
"ssh" will listen to port 22 but only allows private/public key login (via phabricator).
"ssh2" will listen to port 266 with default sshd_config options.

This worked well on Trusty Tahr, but since I've upgraded to Xenial, "ssh2" won't start. It says

```
/etc/init.d/ssh2: 5: /etc/default/ssh2: /etc/ssh2/sshd_config: Permission denied
```

Setup Port 266:

`/etc/ssh`:

```
sudo cp -r /etc/ssh /etc/ssh2
```

Changes in `/etc/ssh2/sshd_config`:

```
Port 266
HostKey /etc/ssh2/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh2/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh2/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh2/ssh_host_ed25519_key
PidFile /var/run/sshd2.pid
```

`/etc/default/ssh`:

```
sudo cp /etc/default/ssh /etc/default/ssh2
```

and changed its content to:

```
SSHD_OPTS=-f /etc/ssh2/sshd_config
```

`/etc/init/ssh.conf`:

```
sudo cp /etc/init/ssh.conf /etc/init/ssh2.conf
```

I changed all occurrences of `ssh`/`sshd` to `ssh2`/`sshd2` and renamed `env SSH_SIGSTOP=1` to `env SSH2_SIGSTOP=1`.

Symbolic links:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/sbin/sshd /usr/sbin/sshd2
sudo ln -s /etc/pam.d/sshd /etc/pam.d/sshd2
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/ssh2 /etc/rc2.d/S03ssh2
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/ssh2 /etc/rc3.d/S03ssh2
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/ssh2 /etc/rc4.d/S03ssh2
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/ssh2 /etc/rc5.d/S03ssh2
```

`/etc/init.d/ssh`:

```
sudo cp /etc/init.d/ssh /etc/init.d/ssh2
```

I changed all occurrences of "`ssh`"/"`sshd`" to "`ssh2`"/"`sshd2`".

Finally I updated iptables:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 266 -j ACCEPT
```

Now, if I want to start service `ssh2` I get the following error:

> Job for ssh2.service failed because the control process exited with
>   error code. See "systemctl status ssh2.service" and "journalctl -xe"
>   for details.

systemctl status ssh2.service:

> ● ssh2.service - LSB: OpenBSD Secure Shell server    Loaded: loaded
>   (/etc/init.d/ssh2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)    Active: failed
>   (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2016-11-19 15:53:46 CET; 44s ago
>        Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)   Process: 2046 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/ssh2 start (code=exited, status=126)
>
> Nov 19 15:53:46 cloud systemd[1]: Starting LSB: OpenBSD Secure Shell
>   server... Nov 19 15:53:46 cloud ssh2[2046]: /etc/init.d/ssh2: 5:
>   /etc/default/ssh2: /etc/ssh2/sshd_config: Permission denied Nov 19
>   15:53:46 cloud systemd[1]: ssh2.service: Control process exited,
>   code=exited status=126 Nov 19 15:53:46 cloud systemd[1]: Failed to
>   start LSB: OpenBSD Secure Shell server. Nov 19 15:53:46 cloud
>   systemd[1]: ssh2.service: Unit entered failed state. Nov 19 15:53:46
>   cloud systemd[1]: ssh2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

journalctl -xe:

> Starting LSB: OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
>   Subject: Unit ssh2.service has begun start-up
>   Defined-By: systemd
>   Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
>   Unit ssh2.service has begun starting up. Nov 19 15:55:57 cloud ssh2[2098]: **/etc/init.d/ssh2: 5: /etc/default/ssh2:
>   /etc/ssh2/sshd_config: Permission denied** Nov 19 15:55:57 cloud
>   systemd[1]: ssh2.service: Control process exited, code=exited
>   status=126 Nov 19 15:55:57 cloud systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB:
>   OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
>   Subject: Unit ssh2.service has failed
>   Defined-By: systemd
>   Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
>   Unit ssh2.service has failed.
>   The result is failed. Nov 19 15:55:57 cloud systemd[1]: ssh2.service: Unit entered failed state. Nov 19 15:55:57 cloud
>   systemd[1]: ssh2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

(I removed the double dashes from `journalctl -xe`).

File permissions:

/etc/ssh2/:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 300261 Aug 11 18:24 moduli
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   1756 Aug 11 18:24 ssh_config
-rw-------   1 root root   2556 Nov 17 23:51 sshd_config
-rw-------   1 root root    668 Apr 18  2015 ssh_host_dsa_key
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    600 Apr 18  2015 ssh_host_dsa_key.pub
-rw-------   1 root root    227 Apr 18  2015 ssh_host_ecdsa_key
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    172 Apr 18  2015 ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
-rw-------   1 root root    399 Aug 19  2015 ssh_host_ed25519_key
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     92 Aug 19  2015 ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
-rw-------   1 root root   1675 Apr 18  2015 ssh_host_rsa_key
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    392 Apr 18  2015 ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    338 Nov 17 19:02 ssh_import_id
```

/etc/ssh2/:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 300261 Nov 17 19:32 moduli
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   1756 Nov 17 19:35 ssh_config
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   2562 Nov 19 14:07 sshd_config
-rw-------   1 root root    668 Mar  1  2016 ssh_host_dsa_key
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    600 Mar  1  2016 ssh_host_dsa_key.pub
-rw-------   1 root root    227 Mar  1  2016 ssh_host_ecdsa_key
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    172 Mar  1  2016 ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
-rw-------   1 root root    399 Mar  1  2016 ssh_host_ed25519_key
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     92 Mar  1  2016 ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
-rw-------   1 root root   1675 Mar  1  2016 ssh_host_rsa_key
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    392 Mar  1  2016 ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    338 Feb 28  2016 ssh_import_id
```

/etc/default/ (trimmed):

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   156 Nov 19 15:18 ssh
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   157 Feb 29  2016 ssh2
```

/etc/init.d/ (trimmed):

```
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  4077 Nov 18 00:38 ssh
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  4121 Nov 18 01:27 ssh2
```

Service-Status:
SSH:

```
ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2016-11-19 15:18:47 CET; 46min ago
 Main PID: 846 (sshd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
           └─846 /usr/sbin/sshd -D -f /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

SSH2:

```
ssh2.service - LSB: OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/ssh2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2016-11-19 15:18:44 CET; 47min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 375 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/ssh2 start (code=exited, status=126)

Nov 19 15:18:44 cloud systemd[1]: Starting LSB: OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Nov 19 15:18:44 cloud ssh2[375]: /etc/init.d/ssh2: 5: /etc/default/ssh2: /etc/ssh2/sshd_config: Permission denied
Nov 19 15:18:44 cloud systemd[1]: ssh2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=126
Nov 19 15:18:44 cloud systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: OpenBSD Secure Shell server2.
Nov 19 15:18:44 cloud systemd[1]: ssh2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 19 15:18:44 cloud systemd[1]: ssh2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Executing the following command (from /etc/initi.d/ssh2) will start the ssh server without any errors. Starting the service via "service ssh2 start" will result in errors!

```
start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --oknodo --pidfile /var/run/sshd2.pid --exec /usr/sbin/sshd2 -- -f /etc/ssh2/sshd_config
```

Summarized:

- service ssh is active (Port 22, currently with default settings)
- service ssh2 won't start
- both services used to work as intended before upgrading to Xenial

I hope, somebody knows, what to do.
Thanks in advance!

Update: Added the `start-stop-daemon` line.

Comment: If you have solved your problem, please consider posting the solution as an answer and not as an update to the question.

Comment: Oh, I haven't seen the answer-button. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Now both ssh instances are running! What did the trick?

I've done the following steps:

- Set `SSHD_OPTS=-f /etc/ssh2/sshd_config` to `SSHD_OPTS=` in `/etc/default/ssh2`
- Set `exec /usr/sbin/sshd2 -D` to `exec /usr/sbin/sshd2 -D -f /etc/ssh2/sshd_config` in `/etc/init/ssh2.conf`
- Uncomment `SSHD_OPTS` in `/etc/init.d/ssh2`
- Set `/usr/sbin/sshd2 $SSHD_OPTS -t || exit 1` to `/usr/sbin/sshd2 -f /etc/ssh2/sshd_config -t || exit 1` in `/etc/init.d/ssh2`
- Set `if start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --oknodo --pidfile /var/run/sshd2.pid --exec /usr/sbin/sshd2 -- $SSHD_OPTS; then` to `if start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --oknodo --pidfile /var/run/sshd2.pid --exec /usr/sbin/sshd2 -- -f /etc/ssh2/sshd_config; then` in `/etc/init.d/ssh2` (**3 occurrences!**)
- reboot

After the reboot both services were running.

Answer (score 0):

Your system is using systemd so you should probably use that.

Copy the current ssh service-file from `/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service` to `/etc/systemd/system/ssh2.service`, edit the new file to your liking and then command: `sudo systemctl enable ssh2 && sudo systemctl start ssh2`